# How to render contents of two models in a single template where one model is linked by Foreign Key through another in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a site for financial purpose. I have two models "Company" and "Reports". Reports model has a foreign key linked to Company. I want to render contents of Company and Reports in a single template in a detail view. When i try to render only one of the model's content is shown not both.. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to display entire data from both tables or specific data related to each other?

Comment: I only want to display data related to each other..like company_name from company model and other fields from Reports table.. i also have company_name as foreign key in reports table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard giving a better example without more details but it would look something like this...

```
    {{ reports_object.company_foreignkey.company_field }}
```